# Select all data corresponding to row in table (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Edit: Using MySQL.

In this example I have a Posts table, a Users table, a Tagged_Posts table, and a Tags table.

The Posts table has a foreign key for user_id that corresponded to the Users table and id column.

The Tagged_posts table has two foreign keys, one for the tag_id and one for the post_id

The Tags table just has an id and a slug.

I'm trying to query posts and have all data related to that post returned, i.e The Post data, the user's data whom the post, and what tags belong to that post.

A single post can have many tags.

This is the SQL query I'm using:

```
$sql = "SELECT posts.title, users.name, users.handle, users.email, tags.slug as tags
from posts 
INNER JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN tagged_posts ON posts.id = tagged_posts.post_id
INNER JOIN tags ON tagged_posts.tag_id = tags.id";
```

Since this particular post has 3 tags associated with it, the query returns the same post 3 times with different values listed for tag. See below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => This is my first Post!
            [name] => exampleuser
            [handle] => example
            [email] => example@gmail.com
            [tags] => database-design
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => This is my first Post!
            [name] => exampleuser
            [handle] => example
            [email] => example@gmail.com
            [tags] => sql
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => This is my first Post!
            [name] => exampleuser
            [handle] => example
            [email] => example@gmail.com
            [tags] => php
        )

)
```

Am I able to do a single query and get everything related to the post?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: MySQL. I'll add that to my question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to concatenate the results together.  For instance, in MySQL, you would do:

```
select p.title, u.name, u.handle, u.email, group_concat(t.slug) as tags
from posts p join
     users u 
     on p.user_id = u.id join
     tagged_posts tp
     on p.id = tp.post_id join
     tags t
     on tp.tag_id = t.id
group by p.title, u.name, u.handle, u.email;
```

Comment: actually, i just came across an issue with the group_concat. If I have multiple posts, it will only show 1 post and add all the tags together even if they dont belong to that post_id. would you like me to edit my question?

Comment: Oh you're right...I'm not sure what happened the first time. It does in fact work as it's supposed to. thanks again

Comment: hey, have another question related to this if you ever get a minute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52139458/sql-query-count-for-related-table-affected-by-other-join